# VS 2017 IDE0006: Error encountered while loading the project -> No log file in trace mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, warnings, intellisense

In a .Net Web Application solution, I get the warning "IDE0006: Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled" on project load, which is leading to errors with compilation and intellisense.

I have tried the [steps listed here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Diagnosing-Project-System-Build-Errors) to launch VS with TraceDesignTime, which is supposed to generate a log file, but there is no log file in the expected location. In addition to that, in my search for a solution, I have seen that most people experiencing this warning are developing an Android application or using a Xamarin package, but I am doing neither of those.

Does anybody have any insight as to why the log file would not be generated, or possibly a different way to diagnose what the real problem with loading the particular project might be?

Comment: Hi Matt, followed the instruction I can generated the expected log file xx.designtime.log, please re-try the step 1-5 and open another solution that you can load correctly before, see if this issue relates to the specific project or not. Meanwhile, you can clean up all folders and files under the folder: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxx\ and restart the VS 2017, open this web application solution. If this issue persists, please run the command: devenv /log to collect log, this file is %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Sara. I doubly confirmed that the problem is with this one specific csproj, and I've tried those steps a few more times and no log file still. I also have tried cleaning up the files in those directories but with no change in behavior. I was able to generate the ActivityLog file, but the only log about that project is this:

Comment: <entry>
    <record>70</record>
    <time>2017/09/07 20:54:03.167</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>MruList</source>
    <description>Entering AddItem. Persistence data for item: D:\dev\dotNet\Universal Partner Integration\Abila\NetForumEnterprise\Abila.NetForumEnterprise.csproj|{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}|False|Abila.NetForumEnterprise||||{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</description>
  </entry>

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I also went pretty far back in source control, and the same warning on the project is occurring, so it doesn't seem to the result of a code/configuration change.

Comment: Hi Matt, refer to your description, it is about the asp.net application development not the intellisense and I help you added the tag "asp.net" to seek for a more professional support.